# React Native Text Trailing Space

Tags: react-native, text-styling, trailing-whitespace

I have a simple **Text** element that loads data from json file,and every thing works fine,
but when i apply styling "justify",i found a big trailing space at the end of the Text and cannot remove it.

i tried trimming **{mydata.trim()}**,
It did not work,or may be the trim worked but applying the Styling **justify** Add the trailing space again.

any Suggestions